# Pandas read_csv wrong values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

i read a csv with duplicate indices with pandas like that:

```
data = pd.read_csv('/home/dev/PycharmProjects/test/download.csv', 
parse_dates=True, index_col=['DATE'], low_memory=False)
print(data.info(memory_usage = 'deep'))
data_extracted = data.groupby(['DATE','ARTICLENO'])['QUANTITY'].sum().unstack()
data_extracted = data_extracted.fillna(value=np.nan)
```

My csv gives for an article number at a specific date the following entries:

```
Quantity, Date
378 2015-01-05 00:00:00.0
450 2015-01-05 00:00:00.0
378 2015-01-05 00:00:00.0
270 2015-01-05 00:00:00.0
432 2015-01-05 00:00:00.0
828 2015-01-05 00:00:00.0
```

The dataframe is shortened to a specific time range:

```
data_extracted = data_extracted.loc['2015-01-01' : '2015-12-31']
```

And then printed. For the specific article number i get the following column:

```
2015-01-05 00:00:00.0    378450378270432828
```

When I use smaller parts of the csv (with nrows=1000000 for example) i do not have this effect.
Can anyone explain me why this happens? I already checked the sum() when doing groupby but i would never achieve such a big value and the big values in the dataframe are continous for all dates found in the csv.

Comment: oh no, just as i saw the raw string i noticed what happened:/

Comment: How do i prevent this concatenation?

Answer (score 0):

There are strings in column, so try convert to `float`:

```
data['QUANTITY'] = data['QUANTITY'].astype(float)
```

If want convert multiple columns:

```
cols = ['QUANTITY','Another col']
data[cols] = data[cols].astype(float)
```

If want convert all columns:

```
data = data.astype(float)
```

If solution above failed use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html):

```
data['QUANTITY'] = pd.to_numeric(data['QUANTITY'], errors='coerce')
```

Comment: I use astype when calculatinf the percentage change, but in my dataframe i have the article number as columns header. Could i do something like this: ´foreach (ColumnHeader c : dataFrame.columns { c.values.astype(float)}´?

Comment: @ItFreak - Answer was modified, loop is not necessary here.

Comment: I think you may missunderstood, my dataframe has the date as index and each column represents a article number so it looks like: article number 1 (values from 'top to down'), article number 2 (values from 'top to down'). Because i read the file dynamically i have no idea what my article numbers in the column are until i print the whole dataframe

Comment: @ItFreak - Yes, so need convert all columns to numeric by `data = data.astype(float)` ?

Comment: if i insert this below my code above i get the following error: could not convert from string to float: 'QUANTITY' which is correct, but that is not what he should do

Comment: Are data confidental? Is possible send me first 5 rows to my email or share data?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176854/discussion-between-itfreak-and-jezrael).